# install tangent (python library for differentiable programming / gradients)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I did pip3 install tangent (Ubuntu 20.04, python 3.8.5), as it's described in https://github.com/google/tangent and I keep fixing and getting errors from Tensorflow, tf-nightly, keras, gast, etc, with the last one being " AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'distributions' ".

Has anybody managed to install and import tangent properly? If so how?

I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would seem that Tangent is designed to work with TensorFlow 1.x. The project looks fairly abandoned. It may work if you install it with [TensorFlow 1.15](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.15.4).

Comment: I will try downgrade Tensorflow to tf 1.15. However pip3 install tangent, downloads tf 2.3.1 automatically. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, as indicated in the link I put above you should try something like `pip install tensorflow==1.15.4` (you may uninstall your version 2.x before, or simply start from a clean virtual environment).